# python -m current directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed my python environment with pip install Some_lib. In my development environment, I have a folder called Some_lib, I would like to execute python -m Some_lib so that the current folder is executed instead of the precedent Some_lib which I installed in the python environment. Possible?

Comment: That is precisely what ``python -m`` does. What makes you think otherwise? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `python -s -m Some_lib` should work as suggested by [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-s):

> `-s`  Don’t add the user site-packages directory to `sys.path`.

but you may have issues importing other modules...

**EDIT**: Actually the current working directory version has precedence by default since

> `-m` [...] As with the `-c` option, the current directory will be added to the start of `sys.path`.

So `python -m Some_lib` should work too.

Comment: Just edited the answer, as I found out that the current directory version of the module has precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it is forbidden to write `python -m .` to run the current module.

Create a directory `some_lib`.
Inside it create a file `__main__.py` with main code,
and create a file '**init**.py'.
Put `some_lib` inside `src`.
Put `src` inside the project directory.
Call the module with `PYTHONPATH=./src/ python -m some_lib`.

See example here: https://github.com/wieczorek1990/hello-worlds/tree/main/python